# Is waiting for the page part of the crawl delay?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been undertaking some fairly large scraping projects (>10000 pages), and some of the websites I am getting information from ask for a crawl delay of 10 seconds. However, to load, get the data from the page, and start the downloads already takes anywhere from 5-8 seconds. I currently have a time.sleep(10) command in there, but that means that now each page is taking closer to 20 seconds total, which is extremely slow with all the pages I hope to be scraping.

Can I count the time that it takes the page to load as part of the 10 second crawl delay, or is it 10 seconds from the time the page fully loads to when the next request can be made?

I'm thinking I could just add some code along the lines of time.sleep(max(0, 10 - time_to_load)), if it isn't breaking the rules.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is dependent on how this particular vendor implemented the timer, but personally I'd assume that it is from start of request to start of request, and see if that causes problems. You should also include code to handle the error returned when you violate the time. It could be 429 error or whatever these guys cook up.

Comment: @DebanjanB - I don't see what is unclear here.

Comment: @tdelaney **unclearness** is reflected through the phrases _dependent on how_. _I'd assume that_, _should also include code_, etc

Comment: @DebanjanB - OP showed `time.sleep(max(0, 10 - time_to_load))`

Comment: I think `time.sleep(max(0, 10 - time_to_load))` is fine, except that it takes people a second to figure it out. If you need to go through a code review, an `if` may raise fewer eyebrows.

Comment: you can set Selenium not to wait for the page to load... set "PageLoadStrategy" in the driver options to PageLoadStrategy.NONE.  That way your 10 sleep after a .get() call is always 10 seconds.